# Error using dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifer

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionreusableview

I have a collection view in a storyboard with 4 collection view cell prototypes with the following identifiers: "Cell", "NoAlbumSelectedCell", "NoPhotosCell" and "NoVideosCell".

This is the code I'm using to load the cells:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
              cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (self.noAlbumSelected) {
    return [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"NoAlbumSelectedCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
}

if ([self.medias count] == 0) {
    if ([self.listType isEqualToString:@"photo"]) {
        UICollectionViewCell *noPhotosCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"NoPhotosCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        return noPhotosCell;
    } else {
        UICollectionViewCell *noVideosCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"NoVideosCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        return noVideosCell;
    }
}

MediaCollectionViewCell *cell = (MediaCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

[self configureCell:cell forItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

return cell;
}
```

When I try to display the "NoPhotosCell" cell, I get the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier NoPhotosCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
```

I tried to do a clean and rebuild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add the following lines at the end of viewDidLoad in your viewController?

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[MediaCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
[self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"NoAlbumSelectedCell"];
[self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"NoPhotosCell"];
[self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"NoVideosCell"];
```

If you have subclasses UICollectionViewCell, then you should use `[YourUICollectionViewSubClass class]` in conjunction with the above lines.

Comment: That worked but now it's not picking up the content in the cells!

Comment: @pedroremedios changed the first line to match what I could see in your code sample.

Answer (score 0):

You have write following code in viewdidload

```
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[CollectionViewImageCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```